# How to rebind View after Error occured in RxBinding?

Tags: android, rx-java

`RxJava` is a wonderful thing because it help me deal with the asychronous task.
But when I use `RxBinding` to bind View with their click events, I find that if error occur and the binding event will not be call anymore.
To  explain my problem ,I simplify my code in an simple Activity.

```
public class Test extends RxAppCompatActivity {
int i = 3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Click");
    setContentView(button);
    RxView.clickEvents(button)
            .compose(this.<ViewClickEvent>bindToLifecycle())
            .map(new Func1<ViewClickEvent, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(ViewClickEvent viewClickEvent) {
                    --i;
                    return 5 / i;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("Test", "Completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("Test", "Error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    Log.d("Test", "Result :" + integer);
                }
            });
     }
}
```

You can see that if i click this button over 3 times logcat will not print log anymore.

I want to know how can I rebind this View after error occured.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to not rely on `onError` at all in this case.

I believe I read somewhere that `onError` in Rx was intended to be used only for *unforeseen* errors and not for normal control flow - much like Exceptions.

So, depending on what you do want to happen in the case that `i` hits `0` you could:

- just put some `onErrorResumeNext()` after the `map` and swallow the error (and maybe replace it with some other value).
- wrap the `Integer` result in some other class, that also has another value to indicate a failure (like for example the `Either` class from https://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Either.html or maybe some other hand-written class).

Another note: I am not sure how much the RxJava community pushes this view but in some other FRP implementations (e. g. Sodium) the functions passed to `map` should very much be *pure*, i. e. they should not influence or be influenced by anything except their inputs.